# Why is Tooltip not displaying?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tooltip

I added a Tooltip to my app.

In the control (a DataGridView) where I want it to display the hint/tooltip, I added verbiage to the "Tooltip on " property. But my verbiage does not display (nothing does, to be precise).

Why?

I added verbiage to a related button, and it works just fine. Maybe the DGV itself cannot deal with tooltips?

**Added**

Here is a complete sample that demonstrates the problem

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var form = new Form {
            Controls = {
                new Button { Name = "button", Location = new Point(10, 10) },
                new DataGridView { Name = "dgv", Location = new Point(10, 50) },
            },
        };

        var tooltip = new ToolTip();
        tooltip.SetToolTip(form.Controls["button"], "Button Tooltip");
        tooltip.SetToolTip(form.Controls["dgv"], "DGV Tooltip");

        Application.Run(form);
        GC.KeepAlive(tooltip); // it's cheaper than implementing IContainer on the form for this demo
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code sample of how this is being added..?

Comment: This is very easy to duplicate. It would take longer to copy and paste code from here than to drop a DGV and ToolTip onto a form and set the DGV's extended property. A perfectly valid question.

Comment: No code - I just dropped the component, and entered the text into the DGV's property.

Comment: Based on your answer. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389439/datagridview-tooltiptext-not-showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [DataGridView ToolTipText not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389439/datagridview-tooltiptext-not-showing)

```
private void dgvPlatypus_CellToolTipTextNeeded(object sender,   DataGridViewCellToolTipTextNeededEventArgs e)
{
    e.ToolTipText = "j. cutworm is a punk";
}
```

Comment: So the workaround is to use the per-cell tooltips built into the DGV. Fine, but the question, "Why can't you get a single 'global' tooltip using the ToolTip control?" lingers.

Answer (score 8):

If you set the datagridviews ShowCellToolTips to false, and then add a general tooltip control to the form and set a text value it will display it.

Comment: it would seem you cannot have both celltooltips and a general one

Comment: This solved it for me. Marcus is right, if the `ShowCellToolTips` property is true (the default) a tooltip you set using the `ToolTip on <tooltip control name>` designer property will not show. IMHO Visual Studio should hide `ToolTip on <tooltip control name>` when `ShowCellToolTips` is true!

Answer (score 3):

Your post is really difficult to understand what you want. I expect you want the tool tip for the DataGridView and not for every cell or row.

If you want a tool tip on the control, not on cell, try this:

```
DataGridView.ShowCellToolTips = False

toolTip1.SetToolTip(DataGridView, "My DataGridView");
```

Comment: Yes, you're right - I simply want a "hint" to display when the user hovers over the DGV; as I added above, it works with a button, but not with the DGV.