# Why is material-ui's tooltip not displaying when nested in a map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

I am using the tooltip component taken from the `@material-ui/core` library. When trying to add a tooltip per cell (i.e. row), I cannot understand why my code is incorrect at producing a localized tooltip for each row. By "localized", I mean that each tooltip is unique to its row.

When using the approach in my code below, the tooltips will not be displayed as expected with the proper handler functions:

```js
function Home({ /* ... */ }) {
  const [ order, setOrder ] = useState('asc')
  const [ orderBy, setOrderBy ] = useState('id')
  const [ open, setOpen ] = useState(false)
  const classes = useStyles()
  const rows = []

  return (
  <TableBody>
    { stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
      .map((row, index) => {
        const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`

        return (
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
              <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={ handleTooltipClose }>
                <Tooltip
                  arrow
                  PopperProps={ {
                    disablePortal: true,
                  } }
                  onClose={ handleTooltipClose }
                  open={ open }
                  disableFocusListener
                  disableHoverListener
                  disableTouchListener
                  title="Unique Tooltip per txn"
                >
                  <div>
                    <button
                      onClick={ handleTooltipOpen }
                      className={ styles.tooltip }
                    >
                      <img
                        src='./eye-tooltip-button.png'
                        className={ styles.tooltipImg }
                        height='12px'
                        width='12px'
                      />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </Tooltip>
              </ClickAwayListener>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell id={ labelId } align="right" size='small'>
              { row.id }
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right" size='small'>{ row.description }</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right" size='small'>{ row.amount }</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right" size='small'>{ row.isCredit }</TableCell>
            <TableCell
              align="right"
              size='small'
              style={ {
                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                maxWidth: '1px'
              } }
            >
              { row.date }
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell
              align="right"
              size='small'
              style={ {
                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                maxWidth: '1px'
              } }
            >
              { row.imageUrl }
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        )
      }) }
  </TableBody>
```

#### The expected behavior is:

1. have a button to the far left, at the start of each row,
2. onClick of a row's button,
3. a tooltip is displayed that contains more data for that row,
4. when you click away from the tooltip, it disappears.

#### Edit 1

I also turned this project into a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-tooltip-nested-under-map-function-2gr1q?file=/pages/index.js) so you all can play around with all of the code to hopefully figure out what's wrong.

#### Edit 2

I'm trying to make a table similar to [Etherscan's table of transactions](https://etherscan.io/txs). So, I'm using it as a reference for what I want to achieve.

#### Related questions

1. [Why is Tooltip not displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432754/why-is-tooltip-not-displaying)

Comment: What is the unexpected behavior, or rather, what is your desired expected behavior? What what I can tell you've a single `open` state, so they all get toggled on/off.

Comment: As per your second link[https://etherscan.io/txs], I think you should not use Tooltip to create this behavior, there is already a component available - https://material-ui.com/components/popper/#popper. This will give you the result you are expecting.